# Java command line parameters for Eclipse-IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I have updated from Eclipse 4.4.2 to 4.7.3 and the new version appears "bigger" than the old one (fonts and graphics). I have "upscaled" my resolution in Windows, but this never had an impact on Eclipse. I know that Java 9 (and higher) "include" the Windows-upscaling, but I am using Java 8. It seems that the newer versions of Eclipse are influenced by the Windows-upscaling.

Is it possible to start Eclipse with the command line parameter -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0 to suppress the new scaling?
I have tried to put this parameter at the start of eclipse, but the following does not work:

```
eclipse.exe -vm -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0 C:\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\javaw -vmargs -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
eclipse.exe -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0 -vm C:\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\javaw -vmargs -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
```

I have searched a lot but I found only descriptions how to modify the command line parameter from eclipse applications (Run-menu), but I do not want to set the run-options of my applications. I want to set the start-options from eclipse itself.

Is it possible to apply the parameter -Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1.0 on the Eclipse-IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse UI uses SWT so java2d settings are not relevant.

The `swt.autoScale` environment variable controls the SWT scaling. The JavaDoc for this says:

> System property that controls the autoScale functionality.
>
> - false: deviceZoom is set to 100%
> - integer: deviceZoom depends on the current display resolution, but only uses integer multiples of 100%. The detected native zoom is
>     generally rounded down (e.g. at 150%, will use 100%), unless close to
>     the next integer multiple (currently at 175%, will use 200%).
> - integer200: like integer, but the maximal zoom level is 200%.
> - quarter: deviceZoom depends on the current display resolution, but
>     only uses integer multiples of 25%. The detected native zoom is
>     rounded to the closest permissible value.
> - exact: deviceZoom uses the native zoom (with 1% as minimal step).
> - <value>: deviceZoom uses the given integer value in percent as zoom level.
>
> The current default is "integer200".

So `-Dswt.autoScale=xxxxx` is what you use.

Comment: Thank you. You are awesome!